# Jquery Ajax Post array of input data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I am writing a thing to compare two passwords with each other, if they match the script sends out a response that says it is the same.

I currently have got this code:

```
$("#repeatPw").keyup(function(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "System/Javascript/Functions/checkPasswords.php",
        data: "'password1'='" + $("#Password").val() + "', 'password2'='" + $("#repeatPw").val() + "'",
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
            $("#passwordMatch").html(data);
        },
        error: function(data) {}
    });
});
```

Now my problem is that i cant get this password1 and password2 in a proper array i can explode in the checkPasswords.php, this posts this:

> Array ( ['password1'] => 'fasfasdfasSD2', 'password2'='asdasdasd' )

But this is not a proper array as it only puts password1 in proper array format, how would i go about making password2 in this format too?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: I wonder why do you have to check this in your server? You could have validated in the client side itself.

Comment: in js, you create arrays like so : `var array = [ ];` Then you can add item in it with `push()`. Another way could be to create a JSON object. `data : {'password1' : $("#Password").val(), 'password2' : $("#repeatPw").val() }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a FormData object:

```
$("#repeatPw").keyup(function(){
  var fd = new FormData();
  fd.append('password1', $("#Password").val());
  fd.append('password2', $("#Password").val());
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "System/Javascript/Functions/checkPasswords.php",
    data: fd,
    type: "POST",
      success: function(data) {
        $("#passwordMatch").html(data);
    },
    error: function(data) {}
  });
});
```

Or do it the JSON way:

```
$("#repeatPw").keyup(function(){
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "System/Javascript/Functions/checkPasswords.php",
    data :{
            password1: $("#Password").val(),
            password2: $("#repeatPw").val(),
            },
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
        $("#passwordMatch").html(data);
    },
    error: function(data) {}
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an array and pass it as the ajax post data,

```
   var data=[];

    data['password1']= $("#Password").val();
    data['password2']= $("#repeatPw").val();
```

Though you could do this in the client side itself.

```
if($("#Password").val().trim() == $("#repeatPw").val().trim())
    //password Matches
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopes this help u..

```
$("#repeatPw").keyup(function(){
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "System/Javascript/Functions/checkPasswords.php",
    data :{
            password1: $("#Password").val(),
            password2: $("#repeatPw").val(),
            },
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
        $("#passwordMatch").html(data);
    },
    error: function(data) {}
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$("#repeatPw").keyup(function(){
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "System/Javascript/Functions/checkPasswords.php",
    data: {'password1' : $("#Password").val(), 'password2' : $("#repeatPw").val() },
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
        $("#passwordMatch").html(data);
    },
    error: function(data) {}
});
 });
```